# Presto-hive access query history

Tags: presto

I'm using `presto` for querying Hive warehouse, I got query history in `presto web interface`. 
Question:

In hive query history logs will available in the Hadoop file system hive path.

Comment: Presto doesn't execute Hive query. It directly accesses HDFS. You can also ask such a question on the community Slack. https://prestosql.io/slack.html

Answer (score 1):

No, the queries Presto executes are not available in HDFS (or anywhere, really). They are temporarily available in-memory on the Coordinator to show in the UI.  What you can do is create an implementation of an [EventListener](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/develop/event-listener.html) in order to receive the queries Presto executes.  You can then do whatever you like with that information, e.g. log it or write it to a database.